# Remove historical data from xDB Sitecore 9

Tags: xdb, xconnect

For Sitecore 6 to 8 on market place is a great tool to manage contacts/interactions from xDB.

(https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Analytics_Database_Manager.aspx )

This module is obsolete for Sitecore 9 because of xConnect.

Does it exist for Sitecore 9 any tool/scripts to remove historical data        older than specified date using various filters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Analytics Database Manager has now versions which are compatible with Sitecore 9.x

For Sitecore 9.0.x download [ADM 4.0.0](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/services/~/download/F7007A4284ED4AECA1542181115A3F2C.ashx?data=ADM.4.0.0&itemId=51a6ab67-a88f-42b6-b820-86b684af6645)

For Sitecore 9.1 download [ADM 4.1.0](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/services/~/download/A8961F7DB15D4579B11C35F8E67101FB.ashx?data=ADM.4.1.0&itemId=51a6ab67-a88f-42b6-b820-86b684af6645)

Unzip ADM and read the documentation on how to install the module. You have to attach a database, add a connection string, copy content to your xconnect instance and run a sql script against your ShardX databases.

Comment: Both links lead to YSOD.

Comment: Updated links: https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB0232559